# php parse xml get attribute

Tags: php, xml, wordpress

I am new in php.

So, i want to parse xml from url like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<all_emp>
<emp_detail>
    <emp emp_name="john"><img>john_1.jpg</img></emp>
    <emp emp_name="john"><img>john_2.jpg</img></emp>
    <emp emp_name="john"><img>john_3.jpg</img></emp>
    <emp emp_name="marry"><img>marry_1.jpg</img></emp>
    <emp emp_name="marry"><img>marry_2.jpg</img></emp>
    <emp emp_name="david"><img>david_1.jpg</img></emp>
</emp_detail>
</all_emp>
```

I created code to parse it like:

```
function get_empname() {
    $url ='http://.../emp_test.xml';
    $xml=simplexml_load_file("$url") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
    foreach($xml->children() as $emp_detail) {
        $source = $xml->emp_detail->emp->attributes()->emp_name . "<br>";
        return $source; 
    } 
}
```

I can parse xml.

But, this is result I get:

```
john
```

I have question for that:

1. how to get all emp_name attribute?
2. if emp_name is same, how to group it?

Thank you for reading!

Comment: Not 100 % sure, but in my opinion your XML has syntax errors. As far as I know its not allowed to have multiple attributes with the same name inside of the same element. (You have multiple `john` in your `emp_detail`). May someone can correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Twinfriends : may be. but with c#, i can parse it. so, when i change it to php and wordpress, i can't. i think code to parse xml is wrong.

Comment: 2. Go research what is known as a _control break_. 3. Have you heard of `if` …? Then where is the actual problem? Don’t know how string comparison works?

Comment: @CBroe: i will try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your XML is being parsed correctly and your only problem is that you are returning from within the loop causing it to run only once. Try the following for emp_name part. This will also return only unqiue names.

```
function create_shortcode_empname()
{
    $url ='http://localhost/emp_test.xml';
    $xml=simplexml_load_file("$url") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
    $names = array();   
    $emps = $xml->children()->emp_detail->emp ; 
    foreach($emps as $emp_detail)
    {
        $source = (string)$emp_detail->attributes()->emp_name; 
        $names[]= $source; 
    } 
    $names = array_unique($names); 
    return implode("<br />", $names);
}

add_shortcode( 'empname_shortcode', 'create_shortcode_empname' );
```

Comment: still like that.

Comment: You mean you still get only first name using this function too?

Comment: Ok I modified the function and tested it too. So it should work now. If it still doesn't, send me your PHP version.

Comment: It work. Thank you so much. But i has another question in post is: how to get img with emp_name is john? Can you do it? Or i need to mark your answer, change post for correct with your answer and post new question?

Comment: I was. Thank you so much.